# What is the proper way to create subtable in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have already implemented a subtable functionality in a QTableWidget. That is, if you click a row that contain a Left Arrow icon, a new row will be added and in there another instance of QTableWidget will be attached using `setCellWidget`.

All is working fine.. until I need to sort the table in an interval bases: this row that contain subtable, should be kinda sticky to its parent row. But, the sort method made them separate. I browse again the documentation, and I found this : [QAbstractItemView#setIndexWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget). I am not sure how to implement this, but it seems like it will make the subtable attached to this row, without the need to add a new row.

Have you face this kind of issue before? Would love to know how you solve it

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I think the proper way is indeed to use [QAbstractItemView.setIndexWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget): it'll keep the data / model untouched so the rows can be properly sorted. We just have to properly display a new widget that don't override the current data appearance